# File download filtering in Cyberduck

Tags: regex

I am trying to download an entire website using Cyberduck without all video files because it will take forever to download them. I have this regular expression string in "Preferences>Transfers>Filter"

```
.*~\..*|\.DS_Store|\.svn|CVS|RCS|SCCS|\.git|\.bzr|\.bzrignore|\.bzrtags|\.hg|\.hgignore|\.hgtags|_darcs|\.wmv|\.mp4|\.flv|\.mov
```

Nothing appears in red (fail to compile). I have also checked "Skip files matching the regular expression", but cyberduck is still downloading files of anything of these extensions.

Any idea?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My only guess is that it looks like the regex is case-sensitive, and the files have upper-case extensions.  Example: `.WMV` isn't matched by `.wmv`.

So, just to try, add this to the end:

```
|\.WMV|\.MP4|\.FLV|\.MOV
```

Comment: I double check the case sensitive settings. It's set to case insensitive. I have no idea what else may have causing it. : (

Answer (score 3):

I think CyberDuck matches the regular expression against the entire filename.  So you need:

```
.+\.WMV|.+\.MP4|.+\.FLV|.+\.MOV
```

So that you match both the name of the file and its extension.

Comment: That is correct. We match the full filename against the regular expression.